# Select on a big mySQL table provokes all connections to switch to status waiting for handler commit

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have an InnoDB table of about 90Gb. I've taken it out of production. Therefore only me is doing operations on it and I don't risk locking issues.

I am looking for a strategy to Select and group by to keep a summary of the data in another table and then delete all the 89Gb.

Everything I have tried seems to take too many resources: After a few minutes, all the connections get stuck on status waiting for handler commit, which is very bad.
(even though no any other user queries this table)
I suspect a problem in memory

So far the best I came up with is this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_into_backup_summary()
BEGIN
    DECLARE d DATE DEFAULT DATE("2020-07-07");
    WHILE d <= "2020-10-16" DO
        INSERT INTO backup_summary
        SELECT NOW() backupDate, userId,
               DATE(createdDate) `date`, COUNT(id) count 
          FROM backup
          WHERE DATE(createdDate) >= d
            AND DATE(createdDate) < DATE_ADD(d, INTERVAL 10 DAY)
          GROUP BY userId, `date`;
        SET d = DATE_ADD(d, INTERVAL 10 DAY);
    END WHILE;
END;
```

But it still blocks all connections after 10-15 minutes.

I tried just a simple `SELECT * FROM backup` and it blocks after a few seconds, which makes me assume the issue is on the SELECT query

Any idea to keep memory fine during the process?

Comment: how many rows do you have i9n 10 days and did you read mysql manual on bulk inserts?

Comment: "delete all the 89Gb" -- Don't use DELETE, instead copy the rows you want to keep to a new table; then use `RENAME TABLE` to shuffle the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your loop is causing a lot of contention on system resources. When I see threads blocked on COMMIT it's usually because the I/O is saturated. In other words, you are forcing so much data to be read from disk that nothing else can get a chance to use the disk.

I notice your conditions are going to cause table-scans for every iteration of your loop. When you use a condition like `DATE(createdDate) >= d` it cannot use an index on `createdDate` even if you have an index on that column. This will happens anytime you use a function on the indexed column. So it has to examine every row in the table instead of just rows between your date range.

To fix this, reference the functions without putting them inside functions:

```
WHERE createdDate >= d AND createdDate < DATE_ADD(d, INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

That should work equally well for selecting the date range, and it will allow an index to be used. That should reduce the demand on the disk.

You might also want to make the loop rest a little bit in between iterations. You can do this:

```
    SET d = DATE_ADD(d, INTERVAL 10 DAY);
    DO SLEEP(10);
END WHILE;
```

This should give a chance for other threads to use the disk storage if they were blocked.

Aside from that, I could ask what type of storage you are using? Because if you have outdated or slow storage, you should take that into account when you do work on 90GB tables.

---

Re your comments:

> @@innodb_log_file_size: 50331648 @@innodb_buffer_pool_size: 4294967296

Your log file size is 50MB which is the [default](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size). I recommend you increase this to at least 1GB. At my company, we set it to 1GB as a starting point, and that's enough for most production apps.

I'm now thinking that as you write so many records so rapidly, you're filling up your innodb log file. When the log file is full, innodb must block commits until some part of the buffer pool is flushed to the tablespace and thus frees up part of the log file to be overwritten. Increasing the size of the log file should allow more writes before you get to this state.

Your buffer pool size is 4GB, which seems small considering you have 128GB of RAM on your server. You should probably increase it by a lot, but you have to keep in mind other processes on your server that may need RAM.

I have a presentation about tuning options. I wrote the presentation when MySQL 5.5 was the current version, but it's still pretty accurate advice.
https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/mysql-55-guide-to-innodb-status

This blog is also very good information:
https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/10/12/mysql-5-7-performance-tuning-immediately-after-installation/

Comment: Thanks Bill, will try out tomorrow when activity is lower in prod.
Here is my hardware:
128GB DDR4 ECC 2400MHz - 2x SSD NVMe 500GB Enterprise Class Soft RAID

Comment: That's pretty good storage hardware. I would expect it to do fine under the load you mention. It's probably the table-scans that are hindering you at this point.

Comment: I tried both removing DATE() in WHERE clause and adding SLEEP and result is the same: After 10 minutes all my connections are frozen.

Comment: Can you query `SELECT @@innodb_log_file_size, @@innodb_buffer_pool_size;` and report their values?

Comment: @@innodb_log_file_size: 50331648
@@innodb_buffer_pool_size: 4294967296

Comment: See my addition in my answer above.

Comment: Thanks so much! For some reason I had it set up to 64G in the past and had commented it. I've just uncommented and it's working all smooth!

Comment: Hi @bill, I was trying to run the query again, and finds the same problem as before. The innodb_buffer_pool_size is set to 64G

Comment: Do you mean in the config file, or does it report as 64G when you query the variable with SELECT as I showed above? It's possible for the real buffer pool size to be different from the value in the config file.

Comment: The SELECT shows @@innodb_log_file_size: 1073741824 and @@innodb_buffer_pool_size: 68719476736

Comment: Well, you can still fill the innodb log file if you are aggressive enough about inserting data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Now I have @@innodb_log_file_size: 10737418240 and @@innodb_buffer_pool_size: 103079215104.       But still getting hanging processes after less than 1 minute even if I query only one day with a SELECT ... WHERE DATE(createdDate) = DATE("2020-10-20")

Comment: You forgot the recommendations I made at the start of my answer?

Comment: My bad Bill! Sorry for that